# Google Maps Javascript API v3 - How to show full info box of company

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Iframe API shows the full company details in an info box in the top left corner:

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Nike+Store+Covent+Garden/@51.5078205,-0.1161565,14z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sNike!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x7dceceff3a6fe610?hl=en

How can this be achieved with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 ?

Comment: You have to get the data (what they make available through the places API) and create it yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Places API mapping a company](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947661/google-places-api-mapping-a-company)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information about a location from Google Maps JavaScript API v3 you would use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). Using this library, you can the name of the building and photos at the location. The api does not display this info for you though. That is up to you.